# Applying Ito's Lemma and integrating, show $\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} W_sdW_s = \frac{1}{2}(W_{t_{i+1}}^2 - W_{t_i}^2 - {\Delta}t)$

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I need to show

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} W_sdW_s = \frac{1}{2}\left(W_{t_{i+1}}^2 - W_{t_i}^2 - {\Delta}t \right)$$

And then apply the result to show

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \left [\int_{t_i}^{s}dW_u \right]dW_s = \frac{1}{2}\left({\Delta}W_{i}^2 - {\Delta}t \right)$$

Could someone please advise how I can approach this? I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than posting a bare problem statement, it's required to give some context for a Question.  The tags and mention (only in title) of Ito's Lemma suggest this is an exercise from a book or course on stochastic processes, so perhaps you could briefly edit the Question to explicitly state the book or class where you encountered it.  Such context may prove valuable to future Readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ito’s Lemma

$$d(W_s^2)=2W_sdW_s+2ds
$$
or
$$W_sdW_s= \frac12(d(W_s^2) -ds)$$
Then, integrate to obtain
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} W_sdW_s
=\frac12(W^2_{t_{i+1}}-W^2_{t_{i}}-\Delta t)
$$